# Options for validates_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, custom-validators

I'm not able to access the values, passed as option in 'validates_with'

My model:

```
    class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    include ActiveModel::Validations
    attr_accessible :name, :uid

    validates :name, :presence => "true"
    validates :uid, :presence => "true"
    validates_with IdValidator, :attr => :uid
```

My Custom Validator:

```
    Class IdValidator < ActiveModel::Validator

    def validate(record)
    puts options[:attr]
    ...
    ...
    end
    end
```

For testing purpose, I'm printing "options[:attr]" and all I see is ":uid" in the terminal and not the value in it. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass in `:attr => :uid`, you're just passing in a symbol.   There's no magic happening here—it just takes the hash of options you've attached and delivers it as the `options` hash.  So when you write it, you see the symbol you've passed.

What you probably want is

```
Class IdValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    puts record.uid
    ...
    ...
  end
end
```

Because `validates_with` is a class method, you can't get the values of an individual record in the options hash.   If you are interested in a more DRY version, you could try something like:

```
class IdValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
    def validate(record)
      puts record[options[:field]]
    end
end


class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  attr_accessible :name, :uid

  validates :name, :presence => "true"
  validates :uid, :presence => "true"
  validates_with IdValidator, :field => :uid
end
```

Where you pass in the name of the field you want evaluated.

Comment: `puts record.uid` works when I just do `validates_with IdValidator` in my model.Problem arises when I have an option along and I want to access it.

Comment: I'm doing this because I'm planning to keep my validator DRY and allow different models to access the same custom validator. Where the name `uid` might have a different name in another model.

Comment: Then what you're looking for is `validates_with IdValidator, :attr => self.uid`, I think?

Comment: `undefined method 'uid' for #<Class:0x007f861d88e208>` is the error, I get on doing that.

Comment: You're right.   My mistake.  I've edited the answer with something I've actually tested this time.